# Invalid handle cumodulegetglobal_v2

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, error

I have RTX 3060TI updated drivers 545 installed. I have an i7 9th gen processor and 64GB RAM with 1 TB M.2 SSD. But this error is still not resolved.

Comment: Try restarting your computer and then render.

Comment: Have you searched the Bug Report section of the [developer](https://developer.blender.org/) website? I would also recommend updating your drivers at the very least. and making sure you're using a new stable version of Blender.

Comment: most likely outdated driver. i found this thread https://developer.blender.org/T96118